# Python package with local dependencies

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a local python project (A) that depends on another local python project (B).
I have added the project B as a git submodule to a dependencies folder.

When I pull the repo with all the submodules, I would like to have a `setup.py` in A such that wenn I run `pip install -e .` in A, it also installs the `setup.py` in B.

The repo looks like this:

```
A
├── A
│   └── foo.py
│  
├── dependencies
│   └── B
│       ├── B
│       │   └── foo.py
│       │
│       └── setup.py
│      
└── setup.py
```

I tried from setuptools import setup, find_packages

```
setup(
    name='A',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

But that only finds package A, which makes sense.

I also tried adding a preinstall command

```
class PreInstallCommand(install):
    """Pre-installation for installation mode."""
    def run(self):
        check_call("pip install -e dependencies/B".split())
        install.run(self)

setup(
    ...

    cmdclass={
        'install': PreInstallCommand,
    },

    ...
)
```

But that one is not triggered when I install it in editable mode (`pip install -e`).

Thanks in advance for your advice! :)

Cheers!

Comment: "*I have added the project B as a git submodule to a dependencies folder.*" Wrong approach. Use Git submodules when you need the code during **development**. Use Python dependencies when you need the code **at runtime**. In your case you shouldn't use Git submodules but declare "B" as a dependency in "A/setup.py".

Comment: And how would you automate getting and installing B if it is not on PyPI etc.?

Comment: Write full path to it — either in "A/setup.py" or in `pip install --find-links=/path`. With Git submodules you do it anyway — you've wrote the path in `.gitmodules`. If "B" is in a repository declare the repository as the dependency — `pip` can install it.